# What's the connection between "Holy Grail" and "Killer Rabbit"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[This article](http://www.jurriaanpersyn.com/archives/2009/02/12/database-sharding-at-netlog-with-mysql-and-php/#databasesetup2) says:

> If there's a Holy Grail, there's a Killer Rabbit.

I can understand that to be "even if there's a good solution, there's a catch to it", but what does *Killer Rabbit* have to do with the *Holy Grail*?

Comment: Bah...Disagree with the closing.

Comment: Too bad you need 800 more points to vote to re-open. I do not see why this is off topic. FAQ: _Usage, word choice, and grammar_ plus _Problems encountered by people learning English_ both apply. The "Explain this joke which uses obscure English" does not apply in my and several other's opinion.

Comment: @MrHen if this question is off topic, then this is off the chart: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33582/grizzly-status/33685#33685

Comment: Once there is a correct answer, you might as well close the question.

Comment: @mplungjan - Yeah, there seem to be rather a lot of questions about idomatic phrases lately. If those are all off-topic I'd understand, but this is the only one of them I've seen get closed. I suppose it could be that the concern was that anything related to Monty Python is bound to go off into the weeds, and the closers couldn't find a more appropriate reason to put down than "off topic".

Comment: @mplungjan: I don't get at-mentions if I am not in the comment history. It is better to make comments like that in [chat].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a reference to a Monty Python film from 1975 called [Monty Python and the Holy Grail](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071853/)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcxKIJTb3Hg

The [Rabbit of Caerbannog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_of_Caerbannog) can be killed by the [Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk).

[image: Rabbit]

Comment: More details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_of_Caerbannog

Comment: Way too many details there ;)))

Comment: 'Tis one of the relics Brother Maynard carries with him!

Comment: Pie Jesu Domine... *clunk*

Comment: ...Dona eis requiem! *clunk*

Answer (score 4):

By way of a long addendum to mplungjan's answer...

If you are going to be interacting a lot with English-speaking people, then as a point of cultural literacy, I highly suggest getting hold of this movie and watching it through at least once. This is probably not the first reference to it you have encountered, and it almost certainly won't be the last. Your typical techie can quote large sections of this film from memory, and knowledge of it is pretty much assumed. (Plus, it's f'ing hilarious)

Other MPatHG references you may stumble across include, but are not limited to:

- Tim the Enchanter
- The Holy Hand Grenade of Antioch
- Air-speed velocity of swallows.
- Answering questions wrong resulting in being thrown in a pit (often: "Red...no Blue. Aieee!")
- Trojan Rabbit
- Sir Robin's Minstrels (occasionally the eating thereof)
- "...and then it fell into the swamp"
- "Runaway!!"
- "`Tis but a scratch!"
- Catapulting cows

Comment: Uhm, can't believe you forgot one word: "Ni"

Comment: Also, the algorithm for witch detection is quite often referenced.

Comment: "Wicked, naughty Zoot." Breaking into song with "Knights of the Round Table."

Comment: Heh. Figured there'd be lots of suggested additions.

Comment: African or European swallows?