# "You went there?" in English

Tags: grammar, expressions, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to add a question mark to show inflection?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/is-it-ok-to-add-a-question-mark-to-show-inflection)

Can we say in a conversation "You went there", and by stressing the statement, mean "Did you go?"

I know one normally asks, "Did you go?". But is the above form also a possibility?

Comment: Noah, given this site is for *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts*, don't you think it would only be reasonable to write "you" rather than "u"? For than reason alone, I'm voting to close as "not constructive"

Comment: @FumbleFingers, since I *had* to edit to fix "possiblity", I fixed "one", which was misspelled as "u".

Comment: @jwpat7: Which was very noble of you, I'm sure. But I didn't vote to close your edit. I voted because I don't like the question. I didn't like [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/) either - but if it suits you, vote to close Noah's as a duplicate of that, because imho it is. Close and delete them both, I say. Also note that Noah neither wrote nor intended "one" - he wrote "u", and meant "you".

Comment: Sorry guys. I was using my iPhone.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, one is what he should have meant. :) Anyhow, I took your advice re duplicate.