# Interrogative sentences without auxiliary verbs and declarative sentences with auxiliary verbs

Tags: grammar, questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to add a question mark to show inflection?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/is-it-ok-to-add-a-question-mark-to-show-inflection)

Sometimes, auxiliary verbs or helping verbs are not present in some interrogative sentences in some specific contexts where they actually appear to be (mostly in simple present tense). Some common examples:

> Where you want to go?
>   What happened to him?
>   How an induction motor starts?
>   Where he lives?
>   What he means?
>   You know?

Why are these sentences not formulated something like the following? Is it just a shortcut way?

> Where do you want to go?
>   What did happen to him?
>   How does an induction motor start?
>   Where does he live?
>   What does he mean?
>   Do you know?